# Customer Export giving product csv

Tags: magento-enterprise

Customer Export giving product csv in enterprice version 1.10.0.1 using system->import/export->dataFlow profiles

Comment: Hi Nived, can you elaborate, it seems you didn't really post a question.

Comment: I am trying to export customers from magento enterprise 1.10.0.1 through system->import/export-> data flow profiles "Export all products"  profile. But after running this profile I am not getting customer data in the csv file, instead of customer data getting all product datas, what could be the problem

Comment: "Export all products" doesn't look like a export CUSTOMER profile ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...you are trying to export customers, but use "Export all **products**" profile and are puzzled why you get products?

Use the "Export **customers**" profile. I bet it will get you the customers.